# How many watts required over PD to charge my notebook

Tags: battery, charging

I have an HP Elitebook that is charged via a USB-C PD port.

I am trying to work out how you work out what is a sufficient power source to charge it - not my specific model, but hopefully the general case.

For example the power supply that comes with it is 75W.  I have a PD battery pack that outputs 65W and it charges it.  It is huge.

If I am not concerned about the speed of charging - perhaps at a minimum it should charge faster than it discharges through normal use, is there a way to find out what that minimum is?

Basically I want to buy a smaller USB battery pack than I have, but the output tends to drop with size, down to 40W or 30W.

Is there a way?

Comment: Less power provided takes more time. Half as much power supplied for charging will take twice as much time.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that a steady drain (charging) on the smaller capacity battery may mean you might not be able to fully charge the battery. Probably enough to work with, but be wary of that.

Comment: The manual should state what power the machine draws.